# Disallow URLs made with mod_rewrite in robots.txts

Tags: seo, htaccess, php, mod-rewrite, query-string

Here is my `robots.txt` file:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /head.php
Disallow: /head/
Disallow: /head
Disallow: /header.php
Disallow: /header/
Disallow: /header
Disallow: /footer.php
Disallow: /footer/
Disallow: /footer
Disallow: /cms.php
Disallow: /cms/
Disallow: /cms
Disallow: /product.php?id=
Disallow: /post.php?id=
```

1. I am wondering if it is necessary for me to disallow crawlers from indexing the `head.php`, `header.php`, `footer.php` and `cms.php` files, as they are included using `include_once`, in the `head`, `header` and `footer` footer sections, respectively, on almost every 
   page of the website (shown below), and therefore they do not make for complete pages by themselves. (`cms.php`, a custom CMS, is included before any HTML on every page.)

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- TEMPLATE -->
    <?php include_once('head.php') ?>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php include_once('header.php') ?>
    <!-- content goes here -->
    <?php include_once('footer.php') ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. I've set up Apache to rewrite all requests for files ending with `.php` to their respective name without `.php`, and with the optional forward slash. Is it necessary that, if I do disallow the mentioned parts of pages, also disallow their re-written URLs?
3. Is it good practice that I hide URLs with query strings if they have their own "custom" re-written URLS? E.g. `/product.php?id=23` → `/products/ice-tea/`

*Note: I've posted this question on [Code Review as well,](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/201384/configuration-of-robots-txt-for-links-made-with-mod-rewrite) but I think that this may be a more suitable place for such a problem. Thanks.*

Comment: Robots.txt rules are "starts with", so most of your rules are redundant.   `Disallow: /head` covers `/head/`, `/head.php` and all the `header` variants as well.  You can make do with just 5 rules without losing any meaning.

Comment: @critical_mass Multiple questions are really not a good fit for the format of this site since they're difficult to answer and vote on. The last question has been asked many times here, click on the [clean-urls](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/clean-urls?sort=votes&pageSize=50) tag or use the Search above. If you edit the question to at least the first two, it will be added to the Review queue for consideration to be reopened.

Comment: Lastly, [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) to more than one Stack Exchange site is frowned upon since that spreads answers out among them. Please post questions to just one site, and then flag it to request that it be migrated to another site if you feel it belongs there instead.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller thanks for that info, I'll make sure to edit it in.

Comment: @dan yes, I'm fully aware of that, but unfortunately I was in need of this information ASAP, so I needed to post it here as well, in the hopes of getting an answer. I'll edit it as soon as I can to fit the recommended guidelines. Thanks!